# Generics that extends string

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have an interface like this

```
interface MyInterface<Q, R> {
    [key: string]: MyAnotherInterface<string, Q, R>
}
```

I would like both strings to be the same, something like this.

```
interface MyInterface<Q, R> {
    [key: T]: MyAnotherInterface<T, Q, R>
}
```

It's very similar to working interface

```
interface ReducerMap<Q, R> {
    <T extends string>(key: T): ReducerGroupFactory<T, Q, R>
}
```

It doesn't work as the key can be only `string` or `number` and T cannot be found. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how are you intending to use `MyInterface`, but you can express a constraint like this with [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types).

Note that you have to have something in `MyAnotherInterface` to make it genuinely incompatible for different values of `Key` (I just added `key: Key` property), otherwise you will get no errors due to structural type compatibility.

```
type MyInterface<Q, R, T extends string> = {
    [Key in T]: MyAnotherInterface<Key, Q, R>
}

class MyAnotherInterface<Key extends string, Q, R> {
    key: Key;
}


let ab: MyInterface<{}, {}, 'a' | 'b'> = {
    'a': new MyAnotherInterface<'b', {}, {}>(),
    'b': new MyAnotherInterface<'b', {}, {}>()
};

// Type '{ 'a': MyAnotherInterface<"b", {}, {}>; 'b':  MyAnotherInterface<"b", {}, {}>; }' 
//  is not assignable to type 'MyInterface<{}, {}, "a" | "b">'.
//      Types of property 'a' are incompatible.
//        Type 'MyAnotherInterface<"b", {}, {}>' is not assignable to type 
//        'MyAnotherInterface<"a", {}, {}>'.
//            Type '"b"' is not assignable to type '"a"'.
```

[code in typescript playround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20MyInterface%3CQ%2C%20R%2C%20T%20extends%20string%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%5BKey%20in%20T%5D%3A%20MyAnotherInterface%3CKey%2C%20Q%2C%20R%3E%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20MyAnotherInterface%3CKey%20extends%20string%2C%20Q%2C%20R%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20key%3A%20Key%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Alet%20ab%3A%20MyInterface%3C%7B%7D%2C%20%7B%7D%2C%20'a'%20%7C%20'b'%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20'a'%3A%20new%20MyAnotherInterface%3C'b'%2C%20%7B%7D%2C%20%7B%7D%3E()%2C%0A%20%20%20%20'b'%3A%20new%20MyAnotherInterface%3C'b'%2C%20%7B%7D%2C%20%7B%7D%3E()%0A%7D%3B)

Comment: I have tried this, to an extent it works but what I am looking for key and value of same t type. Even if pass any of the allowed types in the list it still works. In your example, 'a' key has 'b' type interface value. I would like both to be of the same type.

Comment: All type parameters need to be used in some way by the construct that declares them.